# Google pay not visible on android chrome device if the allowedCardAuthMethod is CRYPTOGRAM 3DS

Tags: google-pay

In Android Chrome, When trying to initialize Google pay with allowedCardAuthMethod as Cryptogram 3ds, not able to view the google pay button

I am trying from India.
sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/dummy4150/8e2cbs6d/

```
const baseRequest = {
  apiVersion: 2,
  apiVersionMinor: 0
};

const allowedCardNetworks = ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"];

const allowedCardAuthMethods = ["CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];

const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    'gateway': 'example',
    'gatewayMerchantId': 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
  }
};


const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
  type: 'CARD',
  parameters: {
    allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods,
    allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks
  }
};


const cardPaymentMethod = Object.assign(
  {},
  baseCardPaymentMethod,
  {
    tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've specified `allowedCardAuthMethods` as `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` and that you are trying from India, Here are a couple of things you could try:

1. Add a tokenized card to Google Pay (one that can be used for Tap and Pay)
2. Generally, Google Pay isn't currently supported in India, join the [`googlepay-test-mode-stub-data`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data) to use predefined test data that can be used in India (more [info](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/test-card-suite))
3. Create a new Google Account for testing based outside of India (suggest using USA) and add a tokenized card to that account

Comment: tried as suggested and able to get the button, thanks